# How do you implement DisposeAsync on an ApiController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, .net-6.0

I have the following code to put a json api over a grpc service. A `ValueTask` is returned when releasing the service activator handle. Code linting suggested that this code should be awaited, but when I refactored to use the `DisposeAsync` pattern `MapControllers` throws an Exception ("DisposeAsync does not have an attribute route").

```
[ApiController]
public class GatewayController : Controller, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly GrpcService _grpcService;
    private readonly IGrpcServiceActivator<GrpcService> _serviceActivator;
    private readonly GrpcActivatorHandle<GrpcService> _activatorHandle;

    public GatewayController(
        IGrpcServiceActivator<GrpcService> serviceActivator, 
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceActivator = serviceActivator;
        _activatorHandle = serviceActivator.Create(serviceProvider);
        _grpcService = _activatorHandle.Instance;
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore();
        Dispose(false);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        // returns a ValueTask that is warned as "should be awaited"
        await _serviceActivator.ReleaseAsync(_activatorHandle);
    }
}
```

How do you implement `DisposeAsync` on an `ApiController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`NonActionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.nonactionattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

> Indicates that a controller method is not an action method.

```cs
[NonAction]
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
   ...
}
```

Or [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

```cs
async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
{
   ...
}
```